# What are JST and WST server adapters?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

Eclipse software installation repository contains two entries

```
WST server adapters
```

ans

```
JST server adapters
```

There are no comprehensive explanations what are these.

For example first is explained as

```
Server adapters for use with the WST server tools
```

and second as

```
Server adapters for use with the JST server tools
```

So they are [sepulcas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sepulka) :)

Eclipse pages for [WST](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/wst/main.php) and [JST](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/main.php) are also contain mambo-yambo.

Is it possible to say what are these both and what are they differ in?

Answer (score 11):

WST

- Stands for web standard tools
- provides support for building multi-tier Web applications
- [WST Link](https://eclipse.org/webtools/wst/main.php)
- The server component contains the Server Tools framework and adapters for selected servers. At the WST level, the server component is a very generic infrastructure.

JST

- Stands for j2ee Standard Tools
- provides support for building multi-tier J2EE applications
- [JST Link](https://eclipse.org/webtools/jst/main.php)
- The server component contains the J2EE Server Tools framework and adapters for selected popular J2EE servers such as Apache Tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

The WST server components provide generic support for servers, whereas the JST components provide specific support for J2EE servers.

If you drill down into the [WST Component](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/wst/components/server/index.html) and [JST Component](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/server/index.html) documentation it gives a bit more detail.