# How can I make JBoss launch block until build workspace is complete?

Tags: eclipse, jboss

In my previous version of Eclipse, I could launch my JBoss server from the same run or debug configurations menu that I use for launching all my other programs, and if I launched the server while "build workspace" was going on, the launch would block until build workspace was complete.

Now that I have upgraded to Luna, if I want to launch JBoss , I have to go to the servers tab because JBoss is no longer listed in the run/debug menus with my other programs, and also, if I launch the server while "build workspace" is going on, the server launches immediately.  Usually this causes a problem because after the build finishes, classes are replaced in the running server JVM, and I get a notice that the hot replace was not successful.

How can I get back to the old behavior for my server?  Is it still possible to have the server launch wait for build workspace to complete?

Comment: have you installed JBoss tools?

Comment: Is your JBoss server launch in the **Run Configurations...** dialog (I'm not talking about the list that shows under the toolbar button)?

Comment: When you upgraded to Eclipse Luna, did you re-install the JBoss server adapter? I'm not sure if it's included when you just install the JBoss developer tools plugins.

Comment: @E-Riz can you clarify the distinction for me between the JBoss server adapter and the JBoss developer tools plugins?

Comment: @Paizo I don't think I installed anything beyond what came with the Luna JEE Eclipse download.

Comment: please try to install jboss tools from the marketplace, then create the server run configuration on the server view and see if it solves the issue

Comment: @skiphoppy: I updated my answer below with some information about server adapters.

Answer (score 3):

Launch configurations are stored in the workspace directory, under the `${workspace_dir}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches` directory. You should be able to find the file corresponding to the launch that used to work there (unless it was deleted during the upgrade to Luna). The name of the file is the same name of the run configuration, e.g. `LaunchServer.launch`.

It could be that the workspace was somehow corrupted after upgrading Eclipse. If you locate the launch configuration file, you can import it by selecting **File --> Import --> Launch Configurations** and browsing the location of the .launch file.

A launch configuration can also be shared if you don't want to store it in the `.metadata` folder. From the configuration dialog, under the **Common** tab, select the **Shared file** radio button to point to the `.launch` file.

See [How do I save Eclipse launch profiles across workspaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952290/how-do-i-save-eclipse-launch-profiles-across-workspaces/) and [How can I clean up Eclipse “run configurations”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247089/how-can-i-clean-up-eclipse-run-configurations).

**EDIT:**

Based on the comments, the workspace seems to already contain the launch configuration file, but it's not showing in the menu. This could possibly be due to some corrupted metadata. You can try to do the following:

1. Copy the existing `.launch` file from `${workspace_dir}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches` to a backup file.
2. Delete the `.launch` file.
3. Restart Eclipse.
4. Import the copied launch config file using **File --> Import --> Launch Configurations**.

Comment: Looks like my JBoss launch configuration is there.  But it still does not show up in the menu.  Starting to wonder if it has to do with the newer JBoss support I'm using.

Comment: I did try importing the JBoss launch configuration that is there, but it asks me if I want to overwrite it.

Comment: @skiphoppy Normally it should appear in the menu after launching it from the Run Configurations dialog (at least once). The menu shows recently launched runs.

Comment: my problem is that when I upgraded to Luna JBoss quit showing up in that menu.  I'm looking to figure out how to get it back.

Comment: The weird thing is that it asks if the launch configuration should be overwritten although it does not show up in the list of launch configurations, which leads me to think it is due to a corrupted workspace...

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247089/how-can-i-clean-up-eclipse-run-configurations) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322663/how-to-remove-launch-configuration-histories-in-eclipse) can help deleting the existing configuration (try to restart Eclipse after deleting). But make sure you backup the already existing file under `${workspace_dir}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches` in case you want to import it.

Comment: I tried deleting the existing JBoss launch configuration file, starting Eclipse, and importing from a copy.  No luck.  Strangely enough, it gave me an error message that "export" of launch configurations failed.

Comment: @skiphoppy What does the failed export say? If you open the "Error Log" view (Window -> Show View -> Error Log), does it show an error message or exception (you can double click on a message in the Error Log to see the exception stacktrace, if any)?

Answer (score 2):

See Run/Debug > Launching in Preferences. Also see ["Launch Groups"](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_run_dbg_launch_group.htm) that allow you to daisy chain run config launches.  More on Launch Groups [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003337/what-installable-component-provides-launch-groups-in-eclipse).

[image]

Comment: I already have that set to Always.  But it has no effect because my server is no longer listed as a launch configuration.

Answer (score 2):

If your JBoss server launch isn't showing up in the **Run Configurations** (or **Debug Configurations**) dialog, it could be that it's being filtered out of the view. Look under **Preferences** > **Run/Debug** > **Launching** > **Launch Configurations** and see the *Filter checked launch types* option, checking if any of the filters might be hiding your server launch.
[image]

---

Another possibility is that you don't have the JBoss tools plugins installed that populate JBoss server launches into the **Run Configurations** list. Make sure you have installed the JBoss Developer Studio or JBoss Tools plugins from Eclipse Marketplace (**Help** > **Eclipse Marketplace** then search for "jboss" (without quotes) in the Marketplace dialog).

Among the things that the JBoss plugins provide is an Eclipse WTP Server Adapter, which enables configuring and launching of JBoss servers in Eclipse Web Tools (see [What are JST and WST server adapters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027578/what-are-jst-and-wst-server-adapters) for some info on WST/JST adapters in Eclipse Web Tools). The JBoss tools provide other features to the IDE, among them might be UI enhancment to list JBoss launches; that's what I suspect you are missing in your Luna installation.

Comment: Thanks, that was good to check, but "filter checked launch configuration types" is turned off.

Comment: @skiphoppy: When you upgraded to Eclipse Luna, did you re-install the JBoss server adapter? I'm not sure if it's included when you just install the JBoss developer tools plugins.